# ostrstream interprets constant string as pointer

Tags: c++, strstream

I ran across this problem while cleaning up the debug macros of an old C/C++ application: We have a Tracer class inheriting from `ostrstream` (I know it's been deprecated since C++98, but this application was written in 1998!) which we use like this:

```
Tracer() << "some" << " message" << " here";
```

Now if the first value in the chain is a constant string like above, the result of calling `ostrstream::str()` on the Tracer (which is done in the destructor, inserting the result into a queue) contains a hexadecimal representation of the pointer to this string instead of the text. Thus the above statement would yield something like `"0x401a37 message here"`. This didn't occur with the old macros as they always had a long (Thread ID) as the first value which has now been removed.

Stepping into it with gdb showed that for the first insertion, this calls `operator<<(void const*)` on the ostrstream, while the subsequent insertions call `operator<< <...>(basic_ostream<...>&, char const*)` (templating removed for readability).

Can somebody explain this behaviour? What would be a clean way to fix this? I have found an easy workaround, which is using `<< left` as the first argument - is this safe? Are there better ways to do this?

Here's a minimized example:

```
#include <strstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Trace : public ostrstream {
    public:
        Trace();
        virtual ~Trace();
};

Trace::Trace() : ostrstream() {}
Trace::~Trace() {
    static_cast< ostrstream& >(*this) <<ends;
    char * text = ostrstream::str();
    cout << "MESSAGE: "<< text <<endl;
    delete[] text;
}

int main(){
    Trace() << "some" << " text" << " here";
    Trace() << left << "some" << " text" << " here";
    Trace() << 123 << " text" << " here";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works this way because the `Tracer()` is a temporary (rvalue) that can not bind to the non-const reference in `operator<<(basic_ostream<...>&,` .

However, you can call member functions like `operator<<(void const*)`, because that doesn't require an lvalue.

The member function then returns a reference to the stream object which *can* be used in calling the next `operator<<` in the sequence.

Calling any member function this way, like `Tracer() << left` or `Tracer() << flush`, and thus "convert" the reference to an lvalue reference is quite safe.

If you happen to have a C++11 compliant compiler, the standard library even contains an `operator<<(basic_ostream<...>&&,` which does this for you. In that case you don't need the workaround anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - see my comment to nawaz' answer, what would be the best workaround for this?

Comment: No, the standard way is to do something like `Tracer() << flush` to get an lvalue reference to the stream. And if you have one of the newest compilers, with rvalue support, it should work anyway. This is an issue that was fixed in the C++11 revision.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The compiler in question is g++ 4.1.2 RedHat, which sadly isn't c++11 compliant...

Comment: @l4mpi: Don't use `std::ostrstream`. It is **deprecated**. Also don't derived from stream classes. Composition is better in this case. Write a wrapper class, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

First of all note that `operator<<` which takes `const char*` as argument is a non-member function. And there exists a member function which takes `void const*` as argument.

In your code, the expression `Trace() << "xyz"` can be invoke only member functions, because `Trace()` creates a temporay, which cannot bind to the first parameter of the non-member `operator<<` functions, as these functions take the first argument as `std::ostream&` which is non-const reference. So `Trace() << "xyz"` resolves to *member* `operator<<` which takes `void*` as argument, which prints the address!

---

My advices:

- Don't inherit from stream class (`std::ostrstream` is **deprecated** anyway).
- Rather write a simple wrapper over stream class and overload `operator<<`

Here is one example:

```
#include <sstream> //for std::ostringstream

struct Trace
{
   std::ostringstream ss;

   template<typename T>
   Trace& operator << (T const & data)
   {
        ss << data;
        return *this;
   }
   ~Trace()
   {
       std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
   }
};
```

Now you can use it as:

```
Trace() << "Hello World\n" << 100 << "\nBye\n";
```

Output:

```
Hello World
100
Bye
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/gfzUd0)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... but, how do I fix this? Is there a better way than prepending `<< left` to all debug statements?

Comment: Thank you, this would have been the best way to implement it... Not sure if we'll use this though as the actual class is somewhat bigger and more complicated and our policy is to make as few changes as possible to the code - this application is almost 15 years old (ostrstream wasn't yet deprecated back then ^^) and most developers who worked on it have left the company a long time ago, so if we break something we're screwed :/

Comment: @l4mpi: The single `operator<<` can print everything as long as it is printable by `std::ostream` because it is template. So it means it will not break anything. If you need extra functionality then you can add to it anytime, with little effort.