# Overload operator<< for text rendering

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I want to create a class which would help me with debugging by providing std::cout or QDebug like functionality using a 3D renderer.

I have the following renderer method which I'm using now

```
IRenderer::renderText(int posX, int posY, const float* color, const char* text, ...);

// E.g.
int i;
float f;
float color[] = {1, 1, 1, 1};

renderer->renderText(50, 50, color, "Float %f followed by int %i", f, i);
```

This actually works fine, but I wonder if it's possible to create a class which would allow me to do it like this:

```
debug() << "My variables: " << i << ", " << "f";
```

I assume there would be a template function which would build the string to pass to `renderText()` based on input type, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to Rob's answer is to include an `ostringstream` in your custom logger class, and use the destructor to do the logging:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyLogger
{
protected:
    std::ostringstream ss;

public:
    ~MyLogger()
    {
        std::cout << "Hey ma, I'm a custom logger! " << ss.str();

        //renderer->renderText(50, 50, color, ss.str());
    }

    std::ostringstream& Get()
    {
        return ss;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int foo = 12;
    bool bar = false;
    std::string baz = "hello world";

    MyLogger().Get() << foo << bar << baz << std::endl;

    // less verbose to use a macro:
#define MY_LOG() MyLogger().Get()
    MY_LOG() << baz << bar << foo << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using macros I suggest you to define `template<class T> MyLogger & operator << (T const &)` for MyLogger class, which would just doing the same with `ss`

Answer (score 0):

I like to derive my logging class from std::ostream, so I get all of the stream goodness. The trick is to put all of your application-specific code in the associated streambuf class. Consider this working example. To modify it to meed your needs, simply rewrite `CLogBuf::sync()`, like so:

```
int sync() { 
  renderer->renderText(50, 50, color, "%s", str());
  str("");
  return false;
}
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

class CLogger : public std::ostream {
private:
    class CLogBuf : public std::stringbuf {
    private:
        // or whatever you need for your application
        std::string m_marker;
    public:
        CLogBuf(const std::string& marker) : m_marker(marker) { }
        ~CLogBuf() {  pubsync(); }
        int sync() { std::cout << m_marker << ": " << str(); str("");  return !std::cout; }
    };

public:
    // Other constructors could specify filename, etc
    // just remember to pass whatever you need to CLogBuf
    CLogger(const std::string& marker) : std::ostream(new CLogBuf(marker)) {}
    ~CLogger() { delete rdbuf(); }
};

int main()
{
    CLogger hi("hello");
    CLogger bye("goodbye");

    hi << "hello, world" << std::endl;
    hi << "Oops, forgot to flush.\n";
    bye << "goodbye, cruel world\n" << std::flush;
    bye << "Cough, cough.\n";
}
```

Comment: You don't even need to create the temporary logger: `CLogger("hello") << "hello, world" << std::endl;`

Comment: @CongXu - Yes, you do need the named object. Temporaries can't bind to  non-const references like `operator>>(ostream&, const char*)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381311/ostrstream-interprets-constant-string-as-pointer

Comment: Any way to do this without using streams?

Comment: Because the code I'm working on uses stlport with iostreams disabled. I have a working solution now using va_list, still wonder how could I implement one using << operator.